# How can I create a folder with date in php

Tags: php

I have an assignment to drag and drop some files on placeholder and upload them to a sever and then create a download link. So I am using PHP, JavaScript and HTML5. But I want to manage these uploaded files in date wise folder.

Can anyone help me to manage these files with dat? Folders will be created according to system date.

Comment: have you tried `mkdir` and `date` ?

Comment: [`date`](http://php.net/date) and [`mkdir`](http://php.net/mkdir) are your friends.

Comment: try `mkdir` to create

Comment: you should search before asking questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for to make the folders?

```
$d = date('h-i-s'); 
mkdir("/path/whatever/" . $d , 0700);
```

Comment: yes it's working but i want current date. now i try this $d = date('m.d.y');

Comment: @RAj Check this link about the date function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I want to write some file in created folder. but it's not working

Comment: $folder = mkdir("uploads/" . date('m.d.y') , 0777, true);
$upload_folder = 'uploads/'.$folder;
if(count($_FILES)>0) { 
 
 exit();
} else if(isset($_GET['up'])) {
 if(isset($_GET['base64'])) {
  $content = base64_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
 } else {
  $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
 }

 $headers = getallheaders();
 $headers = array_change_key_case($headers, CASE_UPPER);
 
 if(file_put_contents($upload_folder.'/'.$folder.'/'.$headers['UP-FILENAME'], $content)) {
  echo 'done';}
 exit();}

Comment: @RAj mkdir(); dosent return the folder name only true/false. To do what your trying to do, do this: $date = date('m.d.y'); mkdir("/path/whatever/uploads/" . $date, 0777, true); $upload_folder = '/path/whatever/uploads/" . $date;

Comment: Thanks it's properly working according to what i want.

Answer (score 0):

try it!

```
$desired_dir= "system_date";<br>
$file_name = 'uploads/'.time().rand(0,999);<br>
if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false)
{
 mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);
}
```

Comment: $upload_folder = 'uploads'; i want to create folder in uploads folder with according to date.